# onActivityResult wasn't called when click home button

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have three activity like this : 
+ LoginPage : display only one time when app installed
+ MainActivity : Home screen of app 
+ TextNoteActivity: Sub activity is called by startActivityForResult from MainActivity

I don't know why when i click up home button from TextNoteActivity. The app will close. 
The following is my code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lilprogramming.bossnote">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="activity.LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="activity.TextNoteActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="activity.MainActivity"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="activity.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="activity.AddTagActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_tag"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </activity>

</application>
```

In MainActivity :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TextNoteActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_ADDTEXTNOTE);
```

In TextNoteActivity :

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.addTextNote_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addTextNote();
            Toast.makeText(TextNoteActivity.this, "Back then", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

**Update**

```
   private void addTextNote() {
    String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
    String content = etContent.getText().toString();

    if (!title.isEmpty() &&  !content.isEmpty()) {
        TextNote textNote = new TextNote(title, 0, content);
        database.addTextNote(textNote, null);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
    }
    else {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }

}
```

Comment: "I don't know why when i click up home button from TextNoteActivity. The app will close." - well, this is the default Android behaviour, what have you expected?

Comment: android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" add this in androidmanifest file   of <application> and try again.

Comment: @Egor Because i want to go back MainActivity. but It closed

Comment: i just update my code. sr about that !

Answer (score 1):

That is expected behavior
There is no reason for your activity to return a result when the user pushes the `Home` button.
If you need to catch the `Home` button event
You could override `onPause()` and `finish()` the activity.

**DISCLAIMER**
But I'm afraid this is not a good app-behavior
Because the user won't expect the app state to change when he pushes the `Home` button.